# In need of a fade out animation for my modal window code

Tags: javascript, html, css, fadeout, modal-window

I just started scripting, and I can't figure out how to add a fade out animation (the same one as the fade in animation ) when closing the modal window.

> Here is a link to the project: https://jsfiddle.net/myosis/kb0o27vy/

I like everything about it, it only needs a closing animation.
Can someone help me out!?

:)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; /* Fade in the background */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5.4s;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 5.4s;
}
/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0px;
    width: 822px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.02),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
} 
/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}
@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut; /* Fade in the background */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5.4s;
    animation-name: fadeOut;
    animation-duration: 5.4s
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.modal-header {
  color: #5B5B5B;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: source-sans-pro, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
}
.modal-body {   
  width: 538px;
  color: #7A7A7A;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: source-sans-pro, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: relative;
  }
.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: blac;
}
/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0}
    to {opacity: 1}
}  
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
    from {opacity: 1}
    to {opacity: 0}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Animated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
          <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u1562-4"><!-- content -->
     <p>test</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u1567-4"><!-- content -->
    <p>test</p>
   </div>
   <div class="colelem" id="u1568"><!-- simple frame --></div>
   <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u1566-4"><!-- content -->
    <p>test</p>
   </div>
   <div class="clip_frame colelem" id="u1556"><!-- image -->
    <img class="block" id="u1556_img" src="" alt="" width="823" height="1024"/>
   </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>-</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use jQuery, here is a quick solution. I have added a `setTimeout` with the duration time of the CSS and after this timeout, the modal is set to `display: none;`. Before the `setTimeout` I have added an animation class to fadeOut the Modal.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the overlay
var overlay = document.getElementById('modalOverlay');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.className = modal.className.replace(/ modalClose/g, '');
  overlay.className = overlay.className.replace(/ modalClose/g, '');
  
  modal.style.display = "block";
  overlay.style.display = "block";
};

overlay.onclick = function() {
  modal.className = modal.className + ' modalClose';
  overlay.className = overlay.className + ' modalClose';
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    overlay.style.display = "none";
  }, 300);
};


// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.className = modal.className + ' modalClose';
  overlay.className = overlay.className + ' modalClose';

  setTimeout(function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    overlay.style.display = "none";
  }, 300);
};

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
}
.u1568 {
  z-index: 23;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #5B5B5B;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: source-sans-pro, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -10000px;
  left: 25px;
}

.u1567-4 {
  z-index: 31;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #9E9E9E;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: source-sans-pro, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-left: 49px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  position: relative;
}

#u1568 {
  z-index: 35;
  width: 538px;
  height: 1px;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
  margin-left: 49px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  position: relative;
}


/* The Modal (background) */
#modalOverlay {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: 99;
}
.modal {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 100;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-left: -150px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  /* Fade in the background */
  -webkit-animation-duration: .3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: .3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0px;
  width: 822px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}


}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}
@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.modalClose {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
  /* Fade in the background */
  
  -webkit-animation-duration: .3s;
  animation-name: fadeOut;
  animation-duration: .3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
/* The Close Button */
.close {

}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.modal-header {
  color: #5B5B5B;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: source-sans-pro, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
}
.modal-body {
  width: 538px;
  color: #7A7A7A;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: source-sans-pro, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: relative;
}
.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: blac;
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }
  
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1
  }
  
  to {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Animated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Overlay -->
<div id="modalOverlay"></div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u1562-4">
        <!-- content -->
        <p>test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u1567-4">
      <!-- content -->
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="colelem" id="u1568">
      <!-- simple frame -->
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u1566-4">
      <!-- content -->
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clip_frame colelem" id="u1556">
      <!-- image -->
      <img class="block" id="u1556_img" src="" alt="" width="823" height="1024" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>-</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I like to explore all options suggested, I have to say @Phil I like yours the best, exactly what I was looking for!
How would I go and add this to the part for wen I click outside the modal window?

Comment: Hey, I have updated my answer and add an overlay. Hope this is what you need. This is a cool jQuery - Plugin for modals: http://flaviusmatis.github.io/easyModal.js/. Its lightweight and easy to understand.

Comment: I'm lost, it got to complicated for me with that overlay, it does works alright!
I was however trying to get rid of the scroll bars within the modal window, but got lost in an endless cycle of getting nowhere :(
Do you maybe have an idea of how to get them back to there original position?

Comment: Hey, this is not complicated ... I have edited the modal size in the CSS file and add an overlay div ... The overlay div acts like the close button. Scrollbars are visible cause I set an overlay attribute inside the modal selector in CSS. The original position of the modal is left:0;top:0; width:100%;height:100%; and margin:0;.

Comment: Ah yea I got it working, really nice, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery to do that

```
$('#myBtn').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').fadeIn(5000);
});

$('.close').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').fadeOut(5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using javascript, so I use the setInterval Function.

Once you want it to close, you use:

```
setInterval(myModal.opacity = myModal.opacity - 0.1, 500);
```

So it changes the opacity by -0.1 every 0.5 seconds. Of course you can change the 500 to suit your fading speed, or the 0.1 to changes how much the opacity goes down by.